# How to defined a variable on PHP?

Tags: php, undefined

//***note: problem solved**//
I'm using uptheme option panel for typography. I'm new in PHP and I'm getting this error:

NOTICE: wp-content/themes/XXXX/admin/library/engines/typography-engine.php:74 - Undefined index:

Line 74 contain this code:

```
$stylesheet = $up_fonts[$font]['style'];
```

I've read answers to similar questions but I've been unable to find a solution for my error.
Please help.
Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: echo "<pre>";
print_r($up_fonts);

Comment: try the above and see if the array contains the index you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly from the error can be read that the current index you are using for the array doesn't exist.

`$up_fonts[$font]['style']` is not set.

You haven't defined your array enough. Check if the value exist with

```
if (isset($up_fonts[$font]['style'])):
  $stylesheet = $up_fonts[$font]['style'];
endif;
```

Comment: Youre welcome. Please "click to set this answer as your accepted answer" with a green check. That is how you say thanks here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an isset conditional around your tags (or something similar to that effect)

```
if (isset($up_fonts[$font]['style'])) {
  // logic here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dasun. I'm using jtheman'code, its similar with yours.